# Can I create a static C array with Cython?

Tags: python, arrays, cython

I'd like to do exactly this in Cython:

```
cdef int shiftIndexes[] = [1,-1, 0, 2,-1, -1, 4, 0, -1, 8, 1, -1, 16, 1, 0, 32, 1, 1, 64, 0, 1, 128, -1, 1]
```

I've seen a few references in fixed bug reports and old email lists that static array functionality exists in Cython, but I can't find anty examples and this particular example gives me a syntax error: `Syntax error in C variable declaration`

Is it possible to make static C arrays with Cython?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use pointer notation instead:

```
cdef int *shiftIndexes = [1,-1, 0, 2,-1, -1, 4, 0, -1, 8, 1, -1, 16, 1, 0, 32, 1, 1, 64, 0, 1, 128, -1, 1]
```

And it will work like a charm.